# Not able to call a .js file dynamically from some HTML page in some browsers

Tags: javascript, blackberry, cross-browser

I call a .js file from my html page like this

```
var value1 = "Hello";
var value2 = "John";

var oHead1 = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0);
var paramScript = document.createElement("script");

paramScript.type = "text/javascript";

        paramScript.setAttribute('value1',
                value1);
        paramScript.setAttribute('value2',
                value2);

oHead1.appendChild(paramScript);

var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0);
var oScript = document.createElement("script");
oScript.type = "text/javascript";
oScript.src = "some.js";
oHead.appendChild(oScript);
```

This works well in Android and iPhone browser. but it doesn't work in Blackberry OS 5.0 browser

Is there an alternative to this which will work in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting an empty script tag with attributes set to the variables, it would make more sense just to use the variables set at the beginning of the script...

```
var value1 = "Hello";
var value2 = "John";
```

This will not only reduce how many DOM manipulations you are incurring, but should also simplify the way you retrieve the variables in some.js.

One more suggestion I can offer is to wrap your JS in a self-calling function.

```
(function(){
    // Code Here
}());
```

Comment: In my HTML i have a variable as "value1" which i need to transfer it to some.js file, so i used paramScript.setAttribute... Is this wrong?

Comment: I would not say it is wrong in theory. However, I would use the HTML5 data attribute (data-value1="Hello") for this to make it standards complaint. What is the HTML you are using?

Comment: I am using phonegap which supports HTML5 but the BB OS 5.0 uses a lower version of HTML... Then what shuld i do?

Comment: Unless I see the JS and HTML you are using, I would not be able to answer that. However, is the problem you are having that the "some.js" file is not loading, or that it is not reading the variable you are setting?

Comment: Actually the above code was working on my other browsers... But this is not working on my earlier BB browser... Ajax is not supported on it... i think so any earlier standard approach will work on it.... I also need to transfer the values to some.js page to make use of it

Answer (score 0):

You should use a library loader like [LAB](http://labjs.com/) or [Frame](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js). There are a lot of browser peculiarities with script loading and the libraries seem to have them all worked out, though I can't speak to Blackberry OS 5.0 specifically.